# JWT Token verification failed with Java.auth0.jwt

Tags: jwt, amazon-cognito

Getting an error when verifying the cognito jwt using Java.auth0.jwt

```
Last encoded character (before the paddings if any) is a valid base 64 alphabet but not a possible value. Expected the discarded bits to be zero.
```

Here is the code and the jwt token i'm working with

jwt token

```
String token = "eyJraWQiOiIwTGh4STAySSs1dUQ5XC9zRm01TXliUEZDSmJHaFwvNEsrcjMxc0l4bW5HZzA9IiwiYWxnIjoiUlMyNTYifQ.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.WrFa3rQoeBzOv5-QQ-BsXkT94FbSpwvSZDXc8I-0yZCR_X2gcuaFEqIUNBePvCa8EeVgaYn9ldkt7-_Cf0RUA3jKx9U9O9q6P29IAYZQ9fWOUcWSo5gEJvGjoijpOI9QZlYfBbekXQvgp4TOtyBj6EZPUg1MMjja5e5DJzSmRMy-JkxPMcKVIbisUYFqv3uezkJg4AWp7kpkYIJKASBm-RODuW3Lc7Zc63lQOO59BVyWo7ar7U62o8QNAWdGU8T9ub1udGIso-oWjV_wC1SWDBbu5HAWNnoCebhTC707JABDGftzYmp";
```

Java code

```
        
        String key = JWT.decode(token).getKeyId();
        JwkProvider jwkProvider = new UrlJwkProvider(JWT.decode(token).getIssuer());
        Jwk jwk = jwkProvider.get(key);
      
        BigInteger modulus = new BigInteger(1, Base64.decodeBase64(String.valueOf(jwk.getAdditionalAttributes().get("n"))));
        BigInteger exponent = new BigInteger(1, Base64.decodeBase64(String.valueOf(jwk.getAdditionalAttributes().get("e"))));
       
        PublicKey publicKey = null;
        try {
            publicKey = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulus, exponent));
        } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
           
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            
        }
        
        Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.RSA256((RSAPublicKey) publicKey, null);
       
        String iss = String.format("https://cognito-idp.%s.amazonaws.com/%s", "us-east-1", "us-east-1_eynKEm7px");

        JWTVerifier verifier = JWT.require(algorithm)
                .withIssuer(iss)
                .withClaim("token_use", "access_token") // make sure you're verifying id token
                .build();
     
        DecodedJWT jwt = verifier.verify(token);
```

Comment: Please show what you've done so far (code, example JWT) so people can reproduce your problem and then help you solve it

Comment: @R.Hoek i have added the code snippet